# How to build specific version of CKEditor with build/wizard tool?

Tags: ckeditor

CKEditor has a build tool here http://ckeditor.com/builder.

Is there way to specify the version you want? In my case I have a compressed version of 4.4.1 and want to upload the build-config.js to download the source for easier debugging. When I upload the build-config.js file it configures it like it was before but using the latest version which is 4.4.7. Maybe there is a version option I can put into the build-config.js?